# Question about total number of drug adverse event reports from 1998-2004

Tags: openfda

Is there a reason why from 1998-2003 the total number of reports in the FDA Adverse Event Database is [235](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:%5B19980824%20TO%2020030729%5D&limit=1) but after one year there were suddenly increased by about [100000](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:%5B19980824%20TO%2020040729%5D&limit=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://fis.fda.gov/extensions/FPD-QDE-FAERS/FPD-QDE-FAERS.html), FAERS data files really start from year 2004. Those 235 records could be outliers that made it into the database as well, but you'd have to contact the FDA directly in case you need a precise answer.